# RxJava and Sqlbrite - what operator to use

Tags: java, android, rx-java, sqlbrite

I started using RxJava in combination with [SqlBrite](https://github.com/square/sqlbrite) and I am having some issues with the `zip` operator.

Let's say I have 2 classes, `User` and `Tweet`.

```
public class User {
    public long id;
    public List<Tweet> users;
    ...
}

public class Tweet {
    public long id;
    public User poster;
    ...
}
```

And their respective SQLite tables:

```
user
---------
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY

tweet
---------
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
poster_id INTEGER
FOREIGN KEY(poster_id) REFERENCES user(id)
```

and their respective SqlBrite DAO

UserDao:

```
public class UserDao {
    private final BriteDatabase briteDb;
    private final TweetDAO tweetDao;

    ...

    public Observable<List<User>> getUsersWithTheirTweets() {
        Observable<User> usersObs = briteDb.createQuery("user", "SELECT * FROM user")
                .map(new Func1<SqlBrite.Query, List<User>>() {
                    @Override
                    public List<User> call(SqlBrite.Query query) {
                        Cursor cursor = query.run();
                        List<User> result = new ArrayList<>(cursor.getCount());
                        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                            User user = UserTable.parseCursor(cursor);
                            result.add(user);
                        }
                        cursor.close();
                        return result;
                    }
                })
                // transform Observable<List<User>> into Observable<User>
                .flatMap(new Func1<List<User>, Observable<User>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<User> call(List<User> users) {
                        return Observable.from(users);
                    }
                });

        // combine each user with his tweets
        return Observable.zip(usersObs, usersObs.flatMap(new Func1<User, Observable<List<Tweet>>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<List<Tweet>> call(User user) {
                return tweetDao.getTweetsByUser(user);
            }
        }), new Func2<User, List<Tweet>, User>() {
            @Override
            public User call(User user, List<Tweet> tweets) {
                user.tweets = tweets;
                return user;
            }
        }).toList();
    }

}
```

TweetDAO:

```
public class TweetDAO {
    private final BriteDatabase briteDb;

    ...

    public Observable<List<Tweet>> getTweetsForUser(final User user) {
        briteDb.createQuery("tweet", "SELECT * FROM tweet WHERE poster_id = ?", Long.toString(user.id))
                .map(new Func1<SqlBrite.Query, List<User>>() {
                    @Override
                    public List<Tweet> call(SqlBrite.Query query) {
                        Cursor cursor = query.run();
                        List<Tweet> result = new ArrayList<>(cursor.getCount());
                        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                            Tweet tweet = TweetTable.parseCursor(cursor);
                            tweet.user = user;
                            result.add(tweet);
                        }
                        cursor.close();
                        return result;
                    }
                })
    }
}
```

As you can see in `UserDao`, I tried to use the a combination of `zip` and `flatMap` operators to populate the list of `Tweet` for each `User`.

First question: is there a better way to do that?

Second question: that `zip` operator seems to hang forever and never completes... I see that `tweetDao.getTweetsByUser(user)` is called but the `Func` of the `zip` is never called... Would anyone have an idea why?

Third question: is there a better way of transforming an `Observable<List<T>>` to an `Observable<T>` other than using a combination of `flatMap` and `from` ?

Damn, that RxJava is powerful but the learning curve is pretty steep...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not let the database handle the join?

```
SELECT * FROM user INNER JOIN tweet ON user._id = tweet.poster_id
```

You might have to rename some columns if the two tables have columns with the same name.

More about joins [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_using_joins.htm)

Comment: I guess that could work too. I would have to group each tweet row per user

Comment: @LordRaydenMk, how about if it was a complex sql and he was using the wrapContentProvider method?